# Run function in another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to run a function from main activity, but function is another fragment. This is my code

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
ConversationFragment fragment = (ConversationFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
fragment.addMessageToList("ok");
```

I placed this code to `onCreate` in `MainActivity`, and this is the `addMessageToList` function in fragment:

```
public void addMessageToList(String message) {
    Log.w("Step 2",message);
}
```

But my app is crashing. Here logcat:

[image]

How can I fix it ?

Comment: can you post the xml you used in your activity

Comment: and also the whole activit

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Main activity:http://pastebin.com/KUmm1Bm0 Fragment:http://pastebin.com/Zrkcpkgc

Comment: Your logcat is complaining about addMessageToFragment() in line 342 of your Activity. What line is that?

Comment: @joao2fast4u ConversationFragment fragment1 = (ConversationFragment)fm1.findFragmentById(R.id.container);

Comment: Could you please show your addMessageToFragment() method?

Comment: @joao2fast4u http://pastebin.com/9DMZVRXQ

Comment: In which Activity are you calling that function?

Comment: Main activity. In onCreate function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59459/discussion-between-joao2fast4u-and-tolgay-toklar).

Comment: Please post the `addMessageToFragment()` method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using `findFragmentById()` when you had no fragment with that id on your `Activity` layout. When replacing a fragment in your container, add a tag to it. Like this:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, frgObj,"ConversationFragment");
```

Then, use `findFragmentByTag("ConversationFragment")` to have your Fragment and execute methods with it.